# Mysql query with full text search and offset when values are equal

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, offset, mysql-variables

I have this table called fruits

```
CREATE TABLE fruits (
  type varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  variety varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  price decimal(5,2) NOT NULL default 0,
  PRIMARY KEY  (type,variety)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

ALTER TABLE fruits ADD FULLTEXT (type, variety);

insert into fruits(type, variety, price) values
('apple',  'gala',       2.79),
('apple',  'fuji',       2.79),
('apple',  'limbertwig', 2.87),
('apple', 'valencia',   0.87),
('orange', 'navel',      9.36),
('pear',   'bradford',   6.05),
('pear',   'bartlett',   2.14),
('cherry', 'bing',       2.55),
('cherry', 'chelan',     6.33);
```

and I am doing a Select query with Full Text Search.

```
select *,
    MATCH (type, variety) AGAINST ('apple') as score
from fruits
WHERE MATCH (type, variety) AGAINST ('apple') > 0 AND price <= 2.79
order by score
LIMIT 2
```

with this result

```
type  | variety | price | score 
-------------------------------
apple | gala    |  2.79 | 0.21812663972377777
apple | fuji    |  2.79 | 0.21812663972377777
apple | valencia | 0.87 | 0.21812663972377777
```

How can I Offset the result by 1 when

- search score  on row 1 = search score on row 2
- price on row 1 = price on row 2

What I want from my query is to return

```
type  | variety | price | score 
-------------------------------
apple | fuji    |  2.79 | 0.21812663972377777
apple | valencia | 0.87 | 0.21812663972377777
```

since

- price = 2.79 on rows 1 and 2
- score = 0.21812663972377777 on rows 1 and 2

Thanks in advance for any potential help

Comment: Which mysql version are you using?

Comment: Hi @ShuwnYuanTee , It is VERSION() 5.6.38